# How to implement my own pop-up control in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, popup, nswindow, nspanel

I want to make a custom autocomplete control for my NSWindow, sort of like Xcode's fancy one, but I can't quite figure out how.

I made an NSPanel with its own NSWindowController, and I display it with some code like:

```
_popupController = [[MYPopupWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName: @"MYPopupPanel"];
NSPanel *popup = [_popupController window];
[popup setFrameTopLeftPoint: ...];  // location of the cursor
[popup setLevel: NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel];
[_window addChildWindow: popup ordered: NSWindowAbove];
[_popupController showWindow: sender];
```

The NSPanel itself has its own subclass which implements `-canBecomeKeyWindow` (returning YES), so that the NSTableView in the popup can receive key events.

This works pretty well.  The only problem I have with this is that when my NSPanel is the key window, the main app NSWindow is not (obviously), which causes the red/yellow/green window controls to go dim.  Clearly, in programs like Xcode, the window controls don't dim every time you start to type a method name.

Am I barking up the wrong tree?  Is NSPanel the wrong way to make a custom pop-up control?  Or is there some way to make an NSPanel become the key window without its parent window (or other windows) dimming their window controls?

EDIT: Is there any way to find out what Xcode is actually using, like whether it's an NSPanel?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `NSNonactivatingPanelMask` flag to your `NSPanel` style (if you use xib just set "Non Activating" checkbox in Attributes inspector).

Comment: This is a useful thing to look at (thanks!), but it wasn't what was causing the problem here.  For some reason, even if the NSPanel wasn't `-canBecomeKeyWindow`, it will still accept keyboard events (and not mess up the parent window's controls, of course).  I'm not sure I understand the Cocoa responder chain, but it works now.